# Winter Bash (Hat Bash)

Tags: discussion

For the last 3 years, Stack Exchange has done a special around Christmas where they have special hats, awarded for a variety of things, that lasts most of the month of December, and maybe a bit more. You can see the wrap up from [last year](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/).

So, the question is, do we want to opt in here and have hats, like most of the other sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I support hats (typically with my head).

Comment: Just submitted the official acceptance to our hat overlords. We're getting hats:-)